# Setting the Classpath through Linux Script

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I need to set 100 jar files through Linux script, so i written this way

The echo result is this way

```
test/lib/xstream-1.3.1.jar:test/lib/test/lib/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar:test/lib/test/lib/xmlsec-1.4.1.jar:test/libtest/lib/xml-apis.jar
```

My question is in windows the jar files will be termnated by semicolon , in linux it is showing a colon (:) is this correct ??

Comment: Does it work?  If yes, then it's correct.

Comment: You proably screwed up with `libtest` instead of `lib/test` on the last one, independent of the colons (which are correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption about the path separators is correct.

Comment: Thanks Jan , Means in Linux  it should be like /home/app1.jar;/home/two.jar;/home/two.jar , Am i correct ??

Comment: On Windows ";" and on Linux ":".

Answer (score 1):

`CLASSPATH` is like `PATH` in that its entries are [separated by a semi-colon on Windows and a colon on other platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#OS_specific_notes).

Comment: See, Windows is less effort than Linux or OSX. You do not need a full colon, but a semi colon will suffice. **Much easier to use**.